# How to define and position elements with CSS inside other elements

Tags: html, css

I am working on a drag and drop query designer using HTML5 with AngularDart and CSS.  For this issue all I really need to figure out is how to format the objects in HTML5 and CSS.  I am running into formatting/positioning issues with the object in CSS.  If you look below I have a div with the class "queryElement".  The queryElementLine, queryElementHead, and queryElementBody sections of the object were already in this object and were formatting/positioning properly.

This UI allows a user to drag and drop one element onto another element.  Once dropped I act upon the object to add the new element as a child, but I need to judge where in my collection of elements to add the new dropped item based on which edge of the drop zone element the new/moved element is dropped on.

I recently added divs with classed called "*something*DropZone" (left,top, right, bottom).  These are objects I want to use to determine where the dragged element is dropped. I want them to mimic the top,left,right, and bottom border. I want them to show a 3px gradient border on :hover so the user can see where they will be dropping the item they are dragging. Below is the element html and images that give a better idea what I am facing and what i want to do.

This is what the element box should look like.

[image: What the element looks like before drag over]

Here is what it looks like when I add a left border div.

[image: What happens when I add the left border class/div]

Everything in the element is pushed down and the left dropzone object with its border stacks above it.  What I want is to position the left dropzone inline with the other query element content.

Here is an image I created to show basically where I would like all 4 dropzones to be positioned:

[image: Example]

What I am mostly looking for is some CSS guidance in how to make the dropzone divs float where the above image shows.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="queryElement"
     (drop)="onDrop($event)"
     (dragstart)="onDragStart($event)"
     draggable="true">

    <div class="queryElementLeftDropZone queryElementLeftDropZoneDragOver"></div>
    <div class="queryElementTopDropZone"></div>
    <div class="queryElementBottomDropZone"></div>
    <div class="queryElementRightDropZone"></div>

    <div class="queryElementLine"></div>
    <div class="queryElementHead noselect">
        <span class="idSpacer">#{{cohortQueryElement.id}}</span>
        <button class="elementButton noselect" (click)="edit()"><img src="/packages/GenomicsPortal/assets/images/PNG icons/Edit.png" /></button>
        <button class="elementButton noselect" (click)="delete()"><img  src="/packages/GenomicsPortal/assets/images/PNG icons/Trash.png" /></button>
        <button class="elementButton noselect" (click)="toggleIncludeExclude()"><img [src]="cohortQueryElement.includeExcludeImagePath"/></button>
    </div>
    <div class="queryElementBody"> {{cohortQueryElement.displayName}} </div>
    <div class="queryElementFoot"> {{cohortQueryElement.displayData}} </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After giving this question some additional thought, I think I will avoid the issue altogether by not adding new objects/elements to hover at the edges.  That solution seems to be causing the formatting issues.

It occured to me, rather putting objects to overlay the edges of the box, I could instead determine x,y ranges defining the top, left, bottom, and right of the existing box and then act based on dragover or drop within those x,y coords.

I will post to let you all know how that works out.